# How does language design influence VM and bytecode design?

Tags: language-design, vm-implementation

For example, how did the design of C# and VB.NET shape the development of CIL (and vice-versa)? What about Java and the JVM? How did the nature of PHP affect the development of HHBC/the HHVM, or Perl and Parrot, or Smalltalk and the VMs for various implementations?

Answer (score 0):

Language design will influence the VM if the designers want it to. Some VMs are more independent than others. For example, Java does not have multiple inheritance, so JVM does not either.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, a language machine (such as the Java Virtual Machine or the .NET CLR) will closely reflect the requirements of the language (Java for the JVM, C# for the CLR) for which it was designed.

For example, pretty much every Java byte code in the original JVM v1.0 was needed by the compiler. One could suggest that the needs of the JavaC compiler author(s) were being provided on demand by the JVM author(s). (It was a small team, so it may have even been the same person.)

The CLR is a bit different, because in addition to C#, they jammed in some stuff to support a pretend-C++ language, which required at least 3 additional op codes (IIRC). Nonetheless, the CLR was pretty much designed just to support C#.

It's interesting to analyze the Android Davlik engine, since it was designed as a JVM-but-without-using-JVM-byte-codes engine. (It is also register based, instead of stack based.)

At some level, the primary decision becomes this: Whether the engine is a low level Turing complete machine (something like a software RISC machine), or whether the engine's primitive language (its IL) is simply a binary form of its primary source code language. The former is more like WASM (arguably general purpose), while the latter is more like the JVM and CLR specs.